# optparse-applicative Backtracking

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, applicative, optparse-applicative

I'm trying to use the [optparse-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.10.0) library in an program which should perform a different action depending on the number of arguments.

For example, the argument parsing for a program which calculates perimeters:

```
module TestOpts where

import Options.Applicative

type Length = Double

data PerimeterCommand
    = GeneralQuadranglePerimeter Length Length Length Length
    | RectanglePerimeter Length Length

parsePerimeterCommand :: Parser PerimeterCommand
parsePerimeterCommand = parseQuadPerimeter <|> parseRectPerimeter

parseQuadPerimeter = GeneralQuadranglePerimeter <$>
                     parseLength "SIDE1" <*>
                     parseLength "SIDE2" <*>
                     parseLength "SIDE3" <*>
                     parseLength "SIDE4"

parseRectPerimeter = RectanglePerimeter <$>
                     parseLength "WIDTH" <*> parseLength "HEIGHT"

parseLength name = argument auto (metavar name)
```

Only the first argument to `<|>` will ever successfully parse. I think some kind of argument backtracking is required, similar to Parsec's `try` combinator.

Any ideas on how to parse alternative sets of arguments, when the first alternative may consume some arguments of the next alternative?

Comment: Looking at the implementation of runParser suggests that it cannot backtrack, but I'm not 100% certain. Can you redesign your program arguments using command sub-parsers?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It could work for a shape perimeter calculation program. But in my actual application separate command sub-parsers wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please note: this answer was written by the optparse-applicative author, Paolo Capriotti.*

You can't do this with optparse-applicative directly. The main feature
of optparse-applicative is that options can be parsed in any order. If
you want to work mainly with arguments (which are positional), you are
better off having two levels of parsers: use `many argument` in
optparse-applicative, then pass the resulting array to a normal parser
(say using Parsec). If you *only* have positional arguments, then
optparse-applicative won't buy you very much, and you could just parse
the arguments manually with Parsec.